# Getting out of sync server response

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

On a successful signup of a user I am currently seeing a mostly empty page with the text `undefined. Redirecting to /app` at the top.

UPDATE:  I should also mention that after form submittal I am redirected to /users. So on /users I see the text mentioned above.

I think it is because of the req.redirect call being within the user.save callback but I am not sure what the fix is.

I am using mongoose for the ORM.

```
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User({
      email:      req.body.email,
      password:   req.body.password
    });

    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        res.send(412, {message: err});
      else
        req.login(user, function(err) {
          if (err !== undefined) return next(err);
          res.redirect('/app', {
            email: user.email,
            id:    user._id
          });
        });
    });

  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the req.login call has to be contained in a password.authenticate callback.  The [example](http://passportjs.org/guide/login/) on the site left that part out.

```
user.save(function(err) {
  if (err)
    res.send(412, {message: err});
  else
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return next(err) }
      if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login') }
      req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.redirect('/app', { email:user.email, id:user._id });
      });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```